# How to get the value of selected displayField in ExtJS Combobox

Tags: extjs, extjs3

How to get the value of selected displayField in ExtJS 3.4 ComboBox?
getValue() returns valueField, but I need other.

Comment: Ok, whatever `valueField` is in your case can you clarify what you need then?

Comment: ComboBox has displayField that shown on the page and valueField that submited to script. I need to get value of displayField of selected item.

Comment: For that there is no easy way to archive this. You can subscribe yourself to the select event, but that will only fire if a user clicks and not it you set the value using `setValue()`. So you will need to extend the combo class to add such a behavior. Dunno if that is an option for you, but the is no other way

Comment: There is an other way. calling [getRawValue()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-method-getRawValue)

Comment: getRawValue() returns valueField value :(

Comment: And store is remote so with getStore().load() need callback function contained other parts of the script. I think it is wrong...

Comment: This is what I meant with [getRawValue() (JSFIDDLE)](http://jsfiddle.net/nFDPx/1/).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

combo.getValue() -> the valueField
combo.getRawValue() -> the displayField

Answer (score 6):

If this is the case,

```
displayField : 'countryName',
valueField  : 'countryId',
```

then following function gives the required displayFiled (Even more than 1 fields are there in store you can get them too)

```
function getFieldValues(combo, nameIn, nameOut){
     try{
          var r = combo.getStore().find(nameIn,combo.getValue());
          return combo.getStore().getAt(r).get(nameOut);
     }
     catch(err){
          return'error';
     }
}
```

Way to get the displayfield or any other filed which is in store :

```
var item = getFieldValues(Ext.getCmp('combo'), 'countryId', 'countryName');
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u just user store.filter(), right? If that, try clear filter and load again like below:

```
onProvinceSelected: function (com,record,index)
{
    var provinceCode = com.getValue();
    var postGrid = this.lookupReference('postgrid');
    if (provinceCode != 0) {
        postGrid.store.filter('ProvinceCode', provinceCode);
    } else {
        postGrid.store.filters.clear();
        postGrid.getStore().load();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the lastSelectionText property of the ComboBox; works fine for me, but it is an undocumented feature and thus may break at any time...

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.ComboBox,
{
    getDisplayValue: function () {
        return this.lastSelectionText;
    }
});
```